# set datetime inside of runCommand in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, runcommand

I have a problem with date and datetime inside runCommand of MongoDB. It has been saving my date in null. I could not use ISODate() because it give a error. The variable $date hasn't show me a error but it storged a null value.

This is the mongoDB's query string that I'm executing from Java application:

```
{
  q: {
    'person_id': '1003', 'authoriz.auth_id': { $ne: '1025' }  },
  u: {
    $addToSet: {
      'authoriz': {
        'decision': "TRUE",
        'start_date': { $date: "2018-02-09 00:00:00.0" },
        'decision_id': 125,
        'decision_dsc': "PERMITED",
        'block_id': "1025"
      }
    },
    $currentDate: {
      'last_modified': true
    }
  },
  multi: false,
  upsert: false
}
```

In Java:

```
DBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(query);
CommandResult result =anyDB.command(dbObject);
```

Instead of  save '2018-02-09 00:00:00.0' value in field start_date it has been storaging  a null value.

Could you help me how I set up my query string to save the date?
Are there any others option How I use date with runCommand?

Answer (score 1):

You don`t have the ISO complaint string so the parser returns null.

Use ISO string and it will be fine. More [`here`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

Something like

```
"'start_date': { $date: \"2018-02-09T00:00:00.000Z\" }"
```

Btw command is low level interface and you should be using methods like `update`, `findAndModify` provided in `DBCollection`.

Comment: So the input string could be manipulated to comply with ISO 8601: `"2018-02-09 00:00:00.0".replace( " " , "T" ).concat( "Z" )`

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify the answer ?